# How to use multiple forms in a single page in django

Tags: python, django

Hi i am pretty new to django. I am making a app for taking tiny notes. You can click on the texts (which is a django forms but it doesnt have the outlines) and edit them. I will make the submit form button appear when we change the content with javascript but for now lets leave it that way.

---

[image]

---

> With the "+" button you can add more Note instances.

Now, the problem is when i want to edit the notes the only way i know is using forms, and when i do that i have to call another form for each Note instance...(i suppose).

What i want on my website is, you can simply edit the content or title by clicking the text area, and submiting it(I can give https://trello.com as an example!).

---

**views.py**

```
def document_page(request, title):
    document = Document.objects.get(title=title)
    notes = document.notes.all()

    form = NoteForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=notes[0])

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/note/document/' + title)

    return render(request, 'note/document_page.html', {'document': document, 'notes': notes, 'form': form})
```

---

**models.py**

```
class Note(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=16, default='note-title')
    content = models.TextField(max_length=512, default='content')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='notes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

---

**forms.py**

```
class NoteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = {'title', 'content',}

        labels = {'title': '', 'content': '',}

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'note_title',
                'style': '''
                    resize: none;
                    text-align: center;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 3em;
                    border: none;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
                ''',
            }),
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'note_content',
                'style': '''
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100px;
                    border: none;
                ''',
            }),
        }
```

---

**document_page.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container d-flex flex-column" style="width: 80%;">
    <center> {{document.title}} Document Page</center>

    <div class="container d-flex flex-wrap">
        {% for note in notes %}
        <div class="card m-4" style="width: 13em;">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form.as_p}}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <div class=" m-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="width: 13em;">
            <a href="{% url 'create-note' document.title %}" class="m-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center btn btn-primary" style="width: 4em; height: 2em;">
                <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Try using django Formset https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/formsets/